# Flutter: ClipOval clipper elevation

Tags: flutter, shadow, elevation, clipper

[Bottom Shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qng2x.png)

Hi I am new to flutter and trying to create this design from Shakuro of dribble. I am getting trouble trying to create elevation for the clipper because the whole rectangle is getting the shadow instead of the clipper only.

Is there a way to put elevation or similar effect like shadow underneath the clipper?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64205781/538284

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can wrap your `child` inside a `Container` with `Circle` shape in your `BoxDecoration` like this:

```
  new Container(
            height: 300.0,
            width: 300.0,
            child: Center(child: Text("Your child here")),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    blurRadius: 5.0,
                    offset: Offset(5.0, 5.0),
                    spreadRadius: 5.0)
              ],
            ),
          )
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I also added a clipoval inside for the image to be round otherwise they were square only :)