# How to add shadow to ClipOval in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have been trying to make a new app being a beginner. So, adding shadows to things is completely new to me.

So, Following is my code:

```
Container(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              ClipOval(
                child: Material(
                  color: Colors.white, // button color
                  child: InkWell(
                    // splashColor: Colors.red, // inkwell color
                    child: SizedBox(
                        width: 46, height: 46, child: Icon(Icons.menu,color: Colors.red,),),
                    onTap: () {},
                  ),
                ),
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Following is the mock:

[image: mock]

Comment: no need for ClipOval, check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Material/type.html

Comment: because I don't know how to use `type` attribute. Can you give an example, So i can try it out.

Comment: `child: Material(
type: MaterialType.circle,
clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
elevation: 4.0,
color: Colors.white,
child: InkWell(
splashColor: Colors.orange,
highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
onTap: () {},
child: SizedBox(
width: 46, 
height: 46, 
child: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.red,),
),
),
),`

Comment: or `child: Container(
width: 46,
height: 46,
decoration: ShapeDecoration(
shape: CircleBorder(),
shadows: [
BoxShadow(color: Colors.black, blurRadius: 4, offset: Offset(2, 2)),
],
),
child: Material(
shape: CircleBorder(),
clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
color: Colors.white,
child: InkWell(
splashColor: Colors.orange,
highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
onTap: () {},
child: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.red,),
),
),
),` if you want to define your own shadow

Comment: of course both versions dont use any `ClipOval`

Comment: Hey man I am actually trying to make a project where I am required to call API and store them in local storage. But dont know how in flutter. While browsing i came across Room, can you suggest how should i approach this.

Comment: in flutter you use [moor](https://pub.dev/packages/moor_flutter), not room

Comment: @pskink Using your solution, the InkWell still displays as a square when tapped. It looks great when just sitting there but when tapped the ink is not contained within the circle.

Comment: @StackUnderflow, not really, bot solutions (with `Material` and `Container` root widget) work just fine: `inkWell` splash is limited to circle, not square

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create your own [CustomClipper](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomClipper-class.html)

```
class CustomClipperOval extends CustomClipper<Rect> {
  @override
  Rect getClip(Size size) {
    return Rect.fromCircle(
        center: new Offset(size.width / 2, size.width / 2),
        radius: size.width / 2 + 3);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Rect> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}

class ClipOvalShadow extends StatelessWidget {
  final Shadow shadow;
  final CustomClipper<Rect> clipper;
  final Widget child;

  ClipOvalShadow({
    @required this.shadow,
    @required this.clipper,
    @required this.child,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: _ClipOvalShadowPainter(
        clipper: this.clipper,
        shadow: this.shadow,
      ),
      child: ClipRect(child: child, clipper: this.clipper),
    );
  }
}

class _ClipOvalShadowPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Shadow shadow;
  final CustomClipper<Rect> clipper;

  _ClipOvalShadowPainter({@required this.shadow, @required this.clipper});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = shadow.toPaint();
    var clipRect = clipper.getClip(size).shift(Offset(0, 0));
    canvas.drawOval(clipRect, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

And then to use it

```
ClipOvalShadow(
  shadow: Shadow(
    color: Colors.amber,
    offset: Offset(1.0, 1.0),
    blurRadius: 2,
  ),
  clipper: CustomClipperOval(),
  child: ClipOval(
    child: Material(
      color: Colors.white, // button color
      child: InkWell(
        // splashColor: Colors.red, // inkwell color
        child: Container(
          width: 46,
          height: 46,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.menu,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {},
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

The Result will be

[image]

Comment: It doesn't give the desired effect. plus making it container has another click event animation

Comment: My mistake. I didn't notice you want shadow only for ClipOval. You can check the updated answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, man. Can I know where you reference for flutter tutorial or doc(obviously other than official doc)

Comment: As everyone i think, Official docs, Stackoverflow, Github examples and google of course. For this question for example you can check this github issue for ClipPath. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25946 You can check the gist link to see the code. https://gist.github.com/coman3/e631fd55cd9cdf9bd4efe8ecfdbb85a7 Then you need just to do some modifications. I think the officials docs are pretty good.

Comment: your solution is overcomplicated: its enough just to use `Material.type` property - see my comments below the original question

Comment: I agree, you are right. For this scenario is overcomplicated. I would also use Material.type (i think thats the way FloatingActionButton works under the hook). I wanted to respond to what the title says. Thanks for your response

Comment: `"I wanted to respond to what the title says"` - because that question is a typical [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 7):

**Adding shadow to ClipOval:**

```dart
Center(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  blurRadius: 50.0,
                  spreadRadius: 10.0,
                )
              ],
            ),
            child: ClipOval(
              child: Image.network(
                'https://i.picsum.photos/id/384/536/354.jpg?hmac=MCKw0mm4RrI3IrF4QicN8divENQ0QthnQp9PVjCGblo',
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

**Output:**

[image]